# Resizing an HTML Select with CSS Breaks Control's Scroll Bar in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, resize, html-select

I'm having a problem with Chrome (v23, Win and Ubuntu). When allowing a select control to be resizable, the scroll bar's down arrow ceases to function--it won't scroll through the options. However, the rest of the scroll bar's functionality continues to work.

```
select {
  resize: both;
  overflow: scroll;
}​
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5He3m/)

The question: Am I doing something wrong, or is the a Chrome bug?

Comment: I filed a bug report with [Chromium](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=168253). I guess we'll  see what they decide to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [Chromium bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=168253) was confirmed as such.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT` (as well as checkbox, radio) is one of those strange elements that's really rendered by the OS, not HTML. The ability to style it via CSS is not well supported.

Comment: FWIW, Firefox handles it properly--the scroll bar it renders still works (including the down arrow button).That's why I'm leaning more toward calling it a bug with Chrome, than to conceding it's an OS problem.

Comment: It's not a specification requirement, therefore it is not a bug.

Comment: If Chrome had chosen not to implement the resizing (like IE), I would agree that it's just an unimplemented feature. However, for it to break part of the existing functionality of the control seems like a bug.